# Interpreting algorithm time complexity analysis

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

Lets say we have the following loop and want to find its time complexity:

```
0: def example_loop(n):
1:     i = 0
2:     while i < n:
3:         print(i)
4:         i = i + 1
```

One possible approach is to first determine that for each individual row it's $\Theta (1)$ (row 4 is $\Theta (1) + \Theta (1) = \Theta (1)$). Thus, the complexity of the loop's body is $\Theta (1) + \Theta (1) = \Theta (1)$. The second line of the code is executed $n + 1$ times while lines 3-4 are executed $n$ times so for the lines 2-4 we get $(n + 1) \cdot \Theta (1) + n \cdot \Theta (1) = \Theta (n) + \Theta (1) + \Theta (n) = \Theta (n)$. Adding the lines 0-1 the result becomes $\Theta (1) + \Theta (1) + \Theta (n) = \Theta (n)$.

However, my study materials offer an alternative approach without an explanation which I don't really understand. In it, all individual lines are still $\Theta (1)$. Similar to the first approach, the lines 3-4 together are also $\Theta (1)$, but after that the solution replaces the $\Theta (1)$ of line 2 with $[A_1; B_1] \cdot 1$ and the complexity of lines 3-4 with $[A_2; B_2] \cdot 1$. From that $[A_1; B_1] \cdot (1 + 1 + 1 + ...) + [A_2; B_2] \cdot (1 + 1 + 1 + ...) = [A_1; B_1] \cdot \Theta (n) + [A_2; B_2] \cdot \Theta (n) = \Theta (n) + \Theta (n) = \Theta (n)$ and after this, the solution proceeds like the first one where we add the first two lines to the rest and get $\Theta (n)$. I have no problem following before the replacement, but I'm hoping for an explanation where exactly do $[A_1; B_1] \cdot 1$ and $[A_2; B_2] \cdot 1$ come from and what is the difference between this and the first approach?

Comment: The meaning of $A,B$ *must* explained somewhere in the text. This notation is weird.

Comment: All these discussions seem overkill. All statements take constant time, and the loop is repeated $n$ times, so $\Theta(an+b)$, simply written $\Theta(n)$.